# In how many possible ways can we put $m$ people (distinct) to $n$ identical (non-numbered) classrooms?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

My first answer was: $$\binom{m+n-1}{m}$$ But then since things are non-numbered (identical classrooms) we have to get rid of overcounted combinations, which I found to be $n!$ ($n$ permutations of classes), so the answer is: $$\binom{m+n-1}{m}\Huge / n!$$

Is my answer correct?

Edit: I'm having doubts now, maybe the answer is just $\binom{m}{n}$?

Comment: Just to confirm, when $n=m=3$, the answer you want is 5, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not $\binom{m+n-1}m$, which would be true if the people were *identical* and the classrooms *distinct*, nor is it that value divided by $n!$.

If classrooms cannot be empty, the answer is by definition given by a [Stirling number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind): $S(m,n)$. If classrooms can be empty, this changes to a sum of Stirling numbers $\sum_{k=1}^nS(m,k)$.

Comment: are you sure that $\binom{m+n-1}m$ is the answer if people were identical and the classrooms distinct? as far as i can tell it should be ${m-1\choose m-n}$ because it's as if we're solving the diophantine equation $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+1)=m$

Comment: @zetafunction Yes, $\binom{m+n-1}m$ for that case. It follows by stars and bars.

Comment: Oh yes. you're right. Can you explain as well why the sum of the Stirling numbers accounts for the empty classrooms?

Comment: @zetafunction The number of non-empty classrooms may be anywhere from $1$ to $n$ inclusive. The Stirling number counts the number of ways to partition the $m$ people into $n$ _non-empty_ classrooms.

Comment: makes sense, thakns a ton!

Comment: another question: what if we want to distribute $m$ identical people to $n$ different classrooms so that no classroom is empty? (I think the answer is ${m-1\choose m-n}$)

Comment: @zetafunction Yeah, you are correct on that regard.